# scoping out docusign for a client

Tags: docusignapi

I just wanted to understand certain terms such as

1) what is a template in context of docusign 
2) What is an envelope an when do we use it ? 
3) What is embedding signature ?

Basically my client wants to populate a pdf contract form with certain data got from a form. Would liek to send the pdf form to get it signed by the client...

Although the form maybe same the data fields in it may change ..

so what approach should be taken

a) template or b) embedded ?

assuming a blank form needs ot be sent for signing how does that work ? does the form goto the client phsycially ? or do they come on your site to sign it ...

i am sorry if i am all over i just wanted to understand the process frolm a developers stand point.

Comment: Just posted a lengthly but detailed answer... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you read up on the [DocuSign Developer Center](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center).  In particular the Explore -> Features section has pages dedicated to Templates and Embedding (among other topics) that have much of this info.

- what is a template in context of docusign

Templates help streamline the sending process by allowing you to - at **design-time** - save document(s), recipients (or placeholder roles for recipients), tab locations and types for those recipients, routing and workflow, and more.  Then at real-time when you want to request a signature you simply match a recipient to a role on your template and they automatically inherit all that previously configured workflow.  The data they enter into their fields will still be specific to them, but things like the location of the signature tabs you've placed for them will always be the same, any conditional or dynamic workflows will be the same, etc.  Templates are very flexible and have many features and options so I suggest you read up on them both through the [Features](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features) -> Templates page but also through the API docs.

An alternative to requesting a signature from a Template is to request a signature on a Document.  This is a similar call except that you need to define the tab locations, recipients, routing, etc every time before sending.  With a template you just define all of that stuff once, at design time.

- What is an envelope an when do we use it?

Definition from Explore page overview:  "*An envelope is basically a "container" used to send documents to recipients. The envelope carries information about the sender and timestamps to indicate the progress of the delivery procedure. It can contain collections of Documents, Tabs and Recipients and is analogous to a physical envelope you would send through the mail*".

An envelope can have as many documents as you want in it (I think there's a total size limitation but that it's set high) and can be addressed to 1 or more recipients (actually up to 1,000 if using Bulk Send feature).  And once the last person is done signing the docs in the envelope a Certificate of Completion (CoC) PDF doc is automatically generated and placed inside the envelope as part of an audit trail for your review.

- What is embedding signature ?

Embedding allows you Embed the signing workflow directly into your website or app or whatever you are building.  The signing still takes place through a DocuSign endpoint but you can generate the unique signing URLs yourself and open in an iFrame or Webview.  You can control the branding around the signing experience and you also have control over where the user is re-directed to after they sign.  See the Features -> [Embedding](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/embedding-docusign) page.

---

Regarding your questions about form fields, yes DocuSign also supports that- you want to use Data Fields (called `textFields` in the API), see the Features -> [Stick-eTabs](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/stick-etabs) page.

Lastly, in terms of what approach should be taken (Template or Embedded) - hopefully my first answer cleared this up but those are not mutually exclusive.  You can create an envelope from a Template or from a Local Document(s), and you can either Embed the signing experience or have it remote (i.e. recipient receives an email to start signing).  To make a recipient an Embedded one, you have to set their `clientUserId` property.  See the links I've referenced.

DocuSign also has sample code in 6 different languages for 9 common API scenarios, including Embedding, Requesting a signature from a Template, on a Document, and more.  See the API Walkthroughs:

http://iodocs.docusign.com/apiwalkthroughs

DocuSign has free code samples in 6 different languages